# Extjs Class System statics

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to define a class with utility functions. I'm using Extjs class system.

I'm doing this in the following way:

```
Ext.ns('Controls.Plugins.Nzok')

Ext.define('Controls.Plugins.Nzok.XUtility', {
     statics : {
         getTest : function(test) { return test }
     }
})
```

Now when I want to use getTest method I have to require the class and to write full class name

```
Ext.define('Controls.Plugins.Nzok', {
    requires : ['Controls.Plugins.Nzok.XUtility'],

    useTest : function() {
        var testResult = Controls.Plugins.Nzok.XUtility.getTest(2);
    }
})
```

My problem is that notation is too long. It's very inconvenient to write down every time Controls.Plugins.Nzok.XUtility. Are there any solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `alternateClassName` config does the trick.

```
Ext.define('Controls.Plugins.Nzok.XUtility', {
    alternateClassName: 'Controls.XUtil',  // <--- this is your shorthand
    statics : {
        getTest : function(test) { return test }
    }
});
```

As a side note, `Ext.define` will automatically create namespaces based on your class name, so `Ext.define('Controls.Plugins.Nzok.XUtility'` will generate the `Controls.Plugins.Nzok` namespace for you.